# Provide all users in network contribute access to TFS instance

Tags: tfs

I have a TFS instance and I want all the users in corp network to be able to access that TFS link. Is there an easy way to do this other than giving each user /security group permission in TFS settings. Similarly I have a requestor field in the TFS form and I want all these users name to be populated in that drop down. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You realize that you need a TFS CAL for each user?

You can create a group in your domain where you add all users then give TFS access to that group.